# Allowing both pre-computed and computed-on-the-fly results

Tags: c++, c++11, generic-programming, const-reference

Consider:

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
    std::vector<int> f(const T &t) const {
        return t.f();
    }
};
```

`T::f` must compute the required vector. However, some `T`'s pre-compute the vector and we would like to avoid creating a copy in such a case. Here is my attempt:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> f() const {
        std::vector<int> res{10, 20, 30}; // computing the vector.
        return res;
    }
};

struct B {
    const std::vector<int> &f() const {
        return v_; // returning reference to pre-computed vector.
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> v_{1, 2, 3};
};

template <typename T>
struct C {
    const std::vector<int> &f(const T &t) const {
        return t.f();
    }
};

int main() {
    using T = B; // For A, we get an error about returning reference to a local.
    C<T> c;
    T t;
    c.f(t);
    return 0;
}
```

As the comment in `main` indicates, for `T=A`, the above code is in error as it is returning a reference to the local variable. How can I accommodate for both `T=A` and `T=B`, such that the pre-computed vector `B::v_` does not get copied?

Comment: Your code is compiled and working: https://ideone.com/xedSqU

Comment: @Zefick It only *appears* to work, but as OP correctly pointed out it returns a reference to a local variable which is UB.

Comment: Why can't you store computed vector in class A? You would solve both copying and syntax problems.

Comment: Use `decltype(auto)` as the return type

Comment: @BlackMoses In the real code, `A::f` computes the vector based on the object's state. In that actual context, storing the result of each invocation of `A::f` in a member variable would be ugly.

Comment: I don't know if this non-ugliness is worth creating and populating same vector two times on each call, when you could have mutable vector that is basically allocated only once (if element count doesn't increase much) and populated once per call. You could even avoid calling `.clear()` each time, just `resize` the vector to the new count of elements and overwrite existing ones.

Comment: @BlackMoses Yes, this is an excellent point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `C::f` return the exact same type as `T::f`, by using `decltype`:

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
    auto f(const T &t) const -> decltype(t.f()) {
        return t.f();
    }
};
```

This will return *by value* when `T = A`, and by `const&` when `T = B`.

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CJ3cOJIVPI8VexQJ)

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt isn't testing what it should. For the pre-computed results to be useful, they need to be persistent. One class needs to do both the computation and the storage.

For example,

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> const & f() const {
        if ( v_.empty() ) {
            v_ = {10, 20, 30}; // computing the vector.
        }
        return v_;
    }
private:
    mutable std::vector<int> v_;
};
```

Another architecture would be to store all the results in one `std::map< X, std::vector >` (or `unordered_map`), if there's some type `X` defining the domain of the function.